# Mysql field convert not displaying other fields in table

Tags: mysql, integration, field

I have a table with two fields I have been supplied the solution for the field that converts the mac address field.

MY ORIGINAL STATEMENT is the following:

```
SELECT  INET_NTOA(ip_address) AS myip,mymac 
FROM table1
```

SOLUTION for the mymac field

```
SELECT
    CONCAT (LEFT (b.mh, 2),':',MID(b.mh,3,2),':',MID(b.mh,5,2),':',MID(b.mh,7,2),':',MID(b.mh,9,2),':',MID(b.mh,11,2))
FROM (
    SELECT LPAD (HEX (a.mac_as_int), 12, '0') AS mh
    FROM (
        SELECT mymac  AS mac_as_int FROM table1 WHERE unique_name='test'
    ) a
) b
```

My problem is that its not displaying the myip field. I just need my script give the results displaying the myip field and mymac field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this

```sql
SELECT INET_NTOA(inet) myip,
       CONCAT(LEFT(mac, 2),':', MID(mac,3,2),':',MID(mac,5,2),':',MID(mac,7,2),':',MID(mac,9,2),':',MID(mac,11,2)) mymac
FROM (SELECT inet, 
             LPAD(HEX(mac), 12, '0') mac
        FROM table1) t
```

Output:

```
|     MYIP |             MYMAC |
--------------------------------
| 10.0.5.9 | 00:00:49:96:02:D2 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9db37/5)**